# rxSwift Button Press Observer Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rx-swift

I have an init that sets up the handling of observers for rxSwift on my viewModel

```
init(login: Observable<String>, password: Observable<String>, buttonPress: Observable<Void>) {
        let userInputs = Observable.combineLatest(login, password) { (login, password) -> (String, String) in
            return (login, password)
        }

        let callFromPress = buttonPress
            .withLatestFrom(userInputs)
            .map { (login, password) in
                self.makeLoginRequest(userLogin: login, loginPassword: password, loginSecret: self.loginSecret, deviceToken: self.deviceToken)
        }
    }
```

However when i tap the button, nothing happens. It is hooked up in the VC as so:

```
buttonPress: self.loginView.loginButton.rx.tap.asObservable()
```

Any solutions as to why the button tap doesn't trigger anything despite no errors?

update:

```
init(login: Observable<String>, password: Observable<String>, buttonPress: Observable<Void>) {
    let userInputs = Observable.combineLatest(login, password) { (login, password) -> (String, String) in
        return (login, password)
    }

    buttonPress.subscribe(onNext: { each in
        print(each)
            .withLatestFrom(userInputs)
            .map { (login, password) in
                self.makeLoginRequest(userLogin: login, loginPassword: password, loginSecret: self.loginSecret, deviceToken: self.deviceToken)
        }
    }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

error:

> Extraneous argument label 'onNext:' in call

Update 2:

```
init(login: Observable<String>, password: Observable<String>) {
    // each time the login and password change, returns login and string value
    didTapLoginButton = { [weak self] _ in
        // allows for strong self reference
        guard let `self` = self else { return }

        Observable.combineLatest(login, password) { (login, password) in
            //
            }
            .subscribe(onNext: { response in
                self.makeLoginRequest(userLogin: login, loginPassword: password, loginSecret: self.loginSecret, deviceToken: self.deviceToken)
                // do something with your response
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `.subscribe`. An observable won’t send events until it has a subscriber.

Example:

```
let observable = Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6]) // won't send events. It's only the declaration.
```

When you subscribe to it, things happen:

```
observable.subscribe(onNext: { each in 
    print(each) // Will print each number
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag) // add a dispose bag
```

I didn't try it but, in your particular case, I would do something like this:

1- In your `viewModel`, add a clousure property:

```
var didTapLoginButton: () -> Void = { _ in }
```

2- In your `viewController` - `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.loginView.loginButton.rx.tap.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in 
        self?.viewModel.didTapLoginButton()
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

3- In your `viewModel`:

```
init(login: Observable<String>, password: Observable<String>) {

    didTapLoginButton = { [weak self] _ in 
        // This let you call self as strong reference instead optional
        guard let `self` = self else { return }

        Observable.combineLatest(login, password) { (login, password) -> (String, String) in
            self.makeLoginRequest(userLogin: login, loginPassword: password, loginSecret: self.loginSecret, deviceToken: self.deviceToken)
        }
        .subscribe(onNext: { response in 
            // do something with your response
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i updated the OP with the code for the button press now but it throws errors on the dispose bag: Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context...i assume there are further issues?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more details I would do in your use case.

Comment: thanks only query is why does it throw "Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '(String, String)'" on the LoginRequest func now?

Comment: Can you add the signature of your `makeLoginRequest()` func?

Comment: I have updated the OP again, i want the api call to go when login is pressed only, in your example it called every time a textfield was updated, i posted my current version now, but i get "Extraneous argument label 'onNext:' in call"...i essentially want to update what the textfield say as types but only make the login call once the button is hit

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was doing

```
subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
```

While I should be doing

```
subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
```

And that wiped away the error